# Autodesk Viewer displays a blurry image

Tags: autodesk-forge

I embedded Autodesk Viewer in my application. When initializing Autodesk.Viewing and creating the viewer, the parent element of the viewer container had the `display` property set to `none`. After setting the parent element's `display` property to `block`, I called `viewer.resize()` and `viewer.impl.invalidate(true)`. However, the entire viewer's display remains blurry.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { autodeskManager } from '@/components/AutodeskViewer/store';

import styles from './index.module.less';

declare const Autodesk: any;

export interface AutodeskViewerProps {
  /** Autodesk application client id */
  clientId: string;
  /** Autodesk application client secret */
  clientSecret: string;
  /** 模型ID */
  urn: string;
}

export interface Token {
  token_type: string;
  expires_in: number;
  access_token: string;
}

export const AutodeskViewer: React.FC<AutodeskViewerProps> = ({
  clientId,
  clientSecret,
  urn,
}: AutodeskViewerProps) => {
  const viewerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const viewerScriptRef = useRef<HTMLScriptElement | null>(null);
  const [viewer, setViewer] = useState<any>(null);

  /**
   * 截图
   *
   * @return {Promise<string>} Blob URL
   *
   * */
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  const getScreenShot = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!viewer) {
      return;
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      viewer.getScreenShot(
        viewerRef.current?.offsetWidth,
        viewerRef.current?.offsetHeight,
        (url: string) => {
          fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.blob())
            .then((blobData) => {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onloadend = () => {
                resolve(reader.result as string);
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([blobData]));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              reject(error);
            });
        },
      );
    });
  }, [viewer, viewerRef]);

  /**
   * 获取Autodesk Token
   */
  const getAutodeskToken = useCallback(async () => {
    const data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    data.append('scope', 'data:read');

    const response = await axios.post<Token>(
      'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token',
      data.toString(),
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`)}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
      },
    );
    return response.data;
  }, [clientId, clientSecret]);

  /**
   * 加载Autodesk Viewer JS文件
   */
  const importAutodeskViewerJs = useCallback(async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src =
        'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js';
      script.onload = () => {
        resolve(true);
      };
      script.onerror = () => {
        reject(false);
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      viewerScriptRef.current = script;
    });
  }, []);

  /**
   * 初始化Autodesk Viewer
   */
  const autodeskViewerInitial = useCallback(async () => {
    await importAutodeskViewerJs();

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(
      {
        language: 'en',
        env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
        api: 'streamingV2',
        getAccessToken: (onTokenReady: (token: string, timeInSeconds: number) => void) => {
          getAutodeskToken()
            .then((token) => {
              onTokenReady(token.access_token, token.expires_in);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
        },
      },
      () => {
        // 创建viewer
        const _viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerRef.current, {
          extensions: ['Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension', 'Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension'],
        });

        const startedCode = _viewer.start();
        if (startedCode > 0) {
          console.error(startedCode);
          return;
        }

        setViewer(_viewer);
        autodeskManager.init(
          _viewer,
          viewerRef.current?.offsetWidth || 0,
          viewerRef.current?.offsetHeight || 0,
        );
      },
    );

    return () => {
        if (viewer) {
            viewer.finish();
            viewer.uninitialize();
        }
        Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();
    };
  }, [importAutodeskViewerJs, setViewer, getAutodeskToken]);

  /** 加载模型 */
  const autodeskLoad = useCallback(() => {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
      urn,
      (doc: any) => {
        const viewable = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        doc.downloadAecModelData();
        if (viewable) {
          viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable).then(() => {});
        }
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    );
  }, [urn, viewer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!viewerRef) {
      return;
    }
    autodeskViewerInitial();

    return () => {
      if (viewerScriptRef.current) {
        viewerScriptRef.current?.parentNode?.removeChild(viewerScriptRef.current!);
      }
    };
  }, [autodeskViewerInitial]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!viewer) {
      return;
    }
    autodeskLoad();
  }, [autodeskLoad, urn, viewer]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container} ref={viewerRef} />
    </>
  );
};
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this other reply the host element of the **Viewer** component should not be hidden or have 0 dimensions when you instantiate `GuiViewer3D`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65309008/4654233